# I am getting this error when I use "?" for conditional rendering: Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When doing this:

```
<p>{errors.fullName?.message}</p>
```

My error is:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (49:21) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Any quick fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
{errors.fullName?.message && <p>{errors.fullName.message}</p>}
```